# Prevent id field to be 0 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a table with an `id` field. This is the part of the query which creates the column.

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

When I insert data, I just set `id` to NULL and mysql set a progressive id number for me. How can I prevent this id to be 0? I'm writing my code so that 0 represent an exception: quite a bad coding style but there's nothing I can do to prevent this without rewriting everything.

So, is there any way to tell mysql never to store zero on the id field?

Thanks!

Comment: What exception it should represent?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;` start with 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `auto_increment` column only increasing numbers get stored in the column starting from 1. So don't worry about it. The DB handles that without any further action needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the initial `AUTO_INCREMENT` value to a positive integer - but I believe it starts with `1` anyway. Just to be sure:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name_here AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```